# Add registry key for every user from Install4j

Tags: install4j

Is there any way we can trigger an addition of a registry key for each user that uses the application?
Right now it seems that whatever value I add somewhere in HKEY_CURRENT_USER it will only be added for the user that trigger the installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enumerate users. In a large network, there may be very many users and it may not be possible to say which of those are "local" users.

Comment: So in short it's not possible...but are not local users suppose to have a "home" folder on local machine? (or even the home folder can be somewhere else?)

Comment: It's possible that you could identify the users that have local home folders, but install4j does not have that functionality.